# Live video stream using GStreamer with Janus or WebRTC on Web Browser

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer, http-live-streaming, janus-gateway

First let me begin by saying - *I am new to Janus / GStreamer / WebRTC.*

I have to stream a remote camera connected on robot hardware using GStreamer and WebRTC on to a browser.

But as a proof of concept, I first wanted to achieve the same with videotestsrc. So, I have been trying to achieve the following:

1. Build a GStreamer Pipeline
2. Send that to Janus using UDPSink
3. Run Janus gateway and show the test video stream on a browser (Chrome and Firefox).

Here is what I have done so far:

**1. Created the following GST Pipeline:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=1024,height=768,framerate=30/1 ! timeoverlay ! x264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.6 port=8004
```

**2. And I am using this modified streamingtest.html code:**
**streamingtest2.js** and **streamingtest2.html**:

```js
var server = null;
if (window.location.protocol === 'http:') {
    server = "http://" + window.location.hostname + ":8088/janus";
} else {
    server = "https://" + window.location.hostname + ":8089/janus";
}

var janus = null;
var streaming = null;
var started = false;
var spinner = null;
var selectedStream = null;


$(document).ready(function () {
    // Initialize the library (console debug enabled)
    Janus.init({
        debug: true, callback: function () {
            startJanus();
        }
    });
});



function startJanus() {
    console.log("starting Janus");
    $('#start').click(function () {
        if (started) {
            return;
        }
        started = true;
        // Make sure the browser supports WebRTC
        if (!Janus.isWebrtcSupported()) {
            console.error("No webrtc support");
            return;
        };
        // Create session
        janus = new Janus({
            server: server,
            success: function () {
                console.log("Success");
                attachToStreamingPlugin(janus);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                console.log("janus error");
            },
            destroyed: function () {
                console.log("destroyed");
            }
        });
    });
}


function attachToStreamingPlugin(janus) {
    // Attach to streaming plugin
    console.log("Attach to streaming plugin");
    janus.attach({
        plugin: "janus.plugin.streaming",
        success: function (pluginHandle) {
            streaming = pluginHandle;
            console.log("Plugin attached! (" + streaming.getPlugin() + ", id=" + streaming.getId() + ")");
            // Setup streaming session
            updateStreamsList();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("  -- Error attaching plugin... " + error);
            console.error("Error attaching plugin... " + error);
        },
        onmessage: function (msg, jsep) {
            console.log(" ::: Got a message :::");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
            processMessage(msg);
            handleSDP(jsep);
        },
        onremotestream: function (stream) {
            console.log(" ::: Got a remote stream :::");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(stream));
            handleStream(stream);
        },
        oncleanup: function () {
            console.log(" ::: Got a cleanup notification :::");
        }
    });//end of janus.attach
}

function processMessage(msg) {
    var result = msg["result"];
    if (result && result["status"]) {
        var status = result["status"];
        switch (status) {
            case 'starting':
                console.log("starting - please wait...");
                break;
            case 'preparing':
                console.log("preparing");
                break;
            case 'started':
                console.log("started");
                break;
            case 'stopped':
                console.log("stopped");
                stopStream();
                break;
        }
    } else {
        console.log("no status available");
    }
}


// we never appear to get this jsep thing
function handleSDP(jsep) {
    console.log(" :: jsep :: ");
    console.log(jsep);
    if (jsep !== undefined && jsep !== null) {
        console.log("Handling SDP as well...");
        console.log(jsep);
        // Answer
        streaming.createAnswer({
            jsep: jsep,
            media: { audioSend: false, videoSend: false },      // We want recvonly audio/video
            success: function (jsep) {
                console.log("Got SDP!");
                console.log(jsep);
                var body = { "request": "start" };
                streaming.send({ "message": body, "jsep": jsep });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("WebRTC error:");
                console.log(error);
                console.error("WebRTC error... " + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("no sdp");
    }
}


function handleStream(stream) {
    console.log(" ::: Got a remote stream :::");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(stream));
    // Show the stream and hide the spinner when we get a playing event
    console.log("attaching remote media stream");
    Janus.attachMediaStream($('#remotevideo').get(0), stream);
    $("#remotevideo").bind("playing", function () {
        console.log("got playing event");
    });
}


function updateStreamsList() {
    var body = { "request": "list" };
    console.log("Sending message (" + JSON.stringify(body) + ")");
    streaming.send({
        "message": body, success: function (result) {

            if (result === null || result === undefined) {
                console.error("no streams available");
                return;
            }
            if (result["list"] !== undefined && result["list"] !== null) {
                var list = result["list"];
                console.log("Got a list of available streams:");
                console.log(list);
                console.log("taking the first available stream");
                var theFirstStream = list[0];
                startStream(theFirstStream);
            } else {
                console.error("no streams available - list is null");
                return;
            }

        }
    });
}

function startStream(selectedStream) {
    var selectedStreamId = selectedStream["id"];
    console.log("Selected video id #" + selectedStreamId);
    if (selectedStreamId === undefined || selectedStreamId === null) {
        console.log("No selected stream");
        return;
    }
    var body = { "request": "watch", id: parseInt(selectedStreamId) };
    streaming.send({ "message": body });

}

function stopStream() {
    console.log("stopping stream");
    var body = { "request": "stop" };
    streaming.send({ "message": body });
    streaming.hangup();
}
```

```html
<!--
// janus-gateway streamingtest refactor so I can understand it better
// GPL v3 as original
// https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway
// https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/html/streamingtest.js
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/5.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/2.3.2/spin.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.1.4/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="janus.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" autocomplete="off" id="start">Start</button><br />
        <div id="stream">
            <video controls autoplay id="remotevideo" width="320" height="240" style="border: 1px solid;">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="streamingtest2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**3. I start the Janus server using:**

```
 sudo /usr/local/janus/bin/janus
```

And my Janus streaming config file (janus.plugin.streaming.jcfg) looks like this (full file here: [janus.plugin.streaming.jcfg on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/1q8c5WMs):

```
rtp-sample: {
    type = "rtp"
    id = 1
    description = "Test Stream - 1"
    metadata = "You can use this metadata section to put any info you want!"
    audio = true
    video = true
    audioport = 8005
    audiopt = 10
    audiortpmap = "opus/48000/2"
    videoport = 8004
    videopt = 96
    videortpmap = "H264/90000"
}
```

**4. Start a local http server on port 8080 and open the streamingtest2.html (my current local IP address is 192.168.1.6):**

```
 192.168.1.6:8080/streamingtest2.html
```

**5.** This start the test page which contains a  tag and a Start button.
When I click the **Start** button, it connects to Janus API on port 8088 and waits for the video stream.
[image]

**6. At the same time, if I see the janus server terminal window, it shows:**
[image]

**7.** **And Gst Pipeline terminal shows this:**
[image]

**8. On the browser, the video tag gets filled with a 5 seconds "black" stream and then stops.**
[image]

Please advise what I am doing wrong (most probably its in the pipeline or some certificate issues in Janus configuration).

Or please advise if this can be achieved in a simpler manner using GStreamer's WebRTCBin?

Please see this Pastebin https://pastebin.com/KeHAWjXx for my Google Chrome console log when all these above steps occur. Please provide some inputs so that I can stream the video using GStreamer and Janus. I also don't know how WebRTCBin comes into use in all this.

Comment: Only thing standing out to me was the janus server logs and the error relating to the mdns lookup. You could try adding a STUN server to your HTML page. That should give you a `srflx` candidate in addition to the mdns `host` candidate.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Can you provide some more information as to where make these changes. I am new to Janus, so not able to figure out.

Comment: I don't know anything about configuring Janus, sorry. Here's an example of how you set a STUN server using the official javascript API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceServer/urls.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will try to study that.

Comment: Hello @PawanPillai, did you finally solve your problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Pleymor, I could not resolve it. So finally I decided to not use Janus and just use GStreamer directly.

Comment: @PawanPillai how did you get this working? Do you have an example

Comment: @Edward, in the end, I found Janus too complex to implement, so I implemented WebRTC using NodeJS. Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67887822/922929 and the question of that post for more details. Basically, we create a GStreamer pipeline and stream it using NodeJS to the client browser. It works well and we have tested 100s of hours of live stream on it with under 400ms delay. Hope it helps (also mentioned it as answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update - September 2021**:
As few people have asked on how I was able to do a workaround, here is what worked for me:

In the end, I found Janus too complex to implement, so I implemented WebRTC using NodeJS.
Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67887822/922929) and the question of that post for more details. Basically, we create a GStreamer pipeline and stream it using NodeJS to the client browser.

It works well and we have tested 100s of hours of live-streaming on it with under 400ms delay.

Comment: Isn't the answer you provided, using `tcpclientsink` instead of WebRTC?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do basically the same as @PawanPillai and I managed to do it with Janus 0.11.8, GStreamer 1.20.3 and VP8 stream.

My `janus.plugin.streaming.jcfg` contains the following entry:

```
rtp-sample: {
    type = "rtp"
    id = 1
    description = "Opus/VP8 live stream coming from external source"
    metadata = "You can use this metadata section to put any info you want!"
    audio = false
    video = true
    videoport = 5004
    videopt = 100
    videortpmap = "VP8/90000"
    secret = "adminpwd"
}
```

And I'm using the following GStreamer pipeline (to feed Janus with my web camera):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src name=cam_src ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! videoconvert ! vp8enc deadline=1 ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5004
```

Then, I just serve this example on another port: https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/html/streamingtest.html
...and when I open it in Chrome, I'm able to see select the stream and see the video.